# wordpress theme no connection

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I'm building a WordPress theme for the first time and a few days back I got a memory size error that didn't make sense to me because there was absolutely nothing special inside, just some simple HTML. Every time I separated the HTML and added the PHP, there was an error. So the solution was it to Update PHP and a lot of people told me the same. Now I did that, and I have an entire different problem.

The page looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

And I can't even login into WordPress anymore. I'm not sure what to do.

I don't know if the header is the problem or the way I wrote the code, or even maybe something totally different.

HEADER CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo("charset");?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php 
    wp_head();
    ?>
    
  </head>
  <body>
      <!--navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Conesphere Links</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--navbar ende-->
```

FUNCTIONS CODE:

```
<?php 

/**
 * 
 * TEMPLATE NAME: functions.php
 * DESCRIPTION: Add features to wordpress theme 
 * 
 */

 function theme_sstyle(){
    /**Include style files */
    wp_enqueue_style("style", get_template_directory_uri() ."/style.css", array(), "1.0");
    wp_enqueue_style("bootstrap","https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", array(), "1.0");


 }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_sstyle');


 function theme_scripts(){
   /**Include script files */
   wp_enqueue_scripts("bootstrap-bundle-js","https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", array(),"5.2.0",true);
   wp_enqueue_scripts("bootstrap-popper","https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js", array(),"5.2.0",true);
   wp_enqueue_scripts("bootstrap-js","https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", array(),"5.2.0",true);



}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts')

?>
```

FRONTPAGE CODE:

```
  <?php 
    get_header();
  ?>
    <!--hero -->
  <div class="main">
   <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/slide1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/slide2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/slide3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!--hero ende -->

    <h1>Hello, world! aa</h1>
    <p>paragraph </p>

    <!--content anfang-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/key.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          <!--content ende-->
          <!--content anfang-->
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/key.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
            <!--content ende-->
              <!--content anfang-->
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/key.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--content ende-->


     <!--content anfang-->
     <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/key.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          <!--content ende-->
          <!--content anfang-->
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/key.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
            <!--content ende-->
              <!--content anfang-->
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/key.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--content ende-->
    <!--main ende-->

    <footer>
      <a href="#">Impressum</a>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <?php 
    get_footer();
  ?>
```

Comment: The first snippet you've shown is the default wordpress `index.php`. Anyway, if you can't login that is not related to your theme. Try clear cookies. `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in `wp-config.php` and see if there's an error and what it is.

Comment: Are you seeing actual PHP code on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of errors:

- Use the single quote in PHP.
- in function `theme_scripts()` you used `wp_enqueue_scripts` but it should be `wp_enqueue_script` remove extra `(s)`
- `theme_scripts` & `theme_sstyle` give proper prefix based names to these functions.
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` if this is your main theme then use `get_template_directory_uri()`
- don't use `TEMPLATE NAME: functions.php` in functions.php docs tag.